# CorelDraw range of page numbering

Tags: print-design, corel-draw

How can I set auto page numbering in CorelDraw. I know there is some macro to do this. But how do I do it for range of pages.

Say I do not need page numbering for a Brochure cover and back pages. All the inner pages should have numbering. I'm using CorelDraw X4. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

(Caveat: I don't have X4 to test this on, but it does work on X6)

Assuming you know how to add page numbering using the macro, try to add that to a new, empty layer. Then hide that layer on the cover and back pages. I think the result will be what you're looking for.

Comment: But this way numbering will start from cover page.

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that you didn't want the first page to be counted at all.  I imagine X4 doesn't have the handy "Page number settings" option that X6 has?

(X6 has _Layout > Insert Page Number_, followed by _Layout > Page Number Settings_)